# Routing to parent's router-outlet from a child component

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I've setup a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GYZOpn2TlqqObqxJENfC?p=preview) to demonstrate what I am trying to ask

I have some components in a web app,

the parent component, `App`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div class="main-container">
      <h2>This is the base. This div must be seen on app pages</h2>
      <a [routerLink]="['Home']"> Home </a> | 
      <a [routerLink]="['Users']"> Users  </a> | 
      <a [routerLink]="['Contact']"> Contact </a>
    </div>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    useAsDefault: true

  },
  {
    path: '/users/...',
    name: 'Users',
    component: UsersComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/contact',
    name: 'Contact',
    component: ContactComponent
  }
])
export class App {

}
```

`UsersComponent` is loaded to the `router-outlet` of the parent controller at the route `/users` which is shown below,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template : `

    <div  *ngFor="#page of pages">
      <a [routerLink]="[page.name]">
        {{page.slug}}
      </a>
    </div>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path : '/', name: 'Main', component: MainRoute, useAsDefault: true}  
])
export class UsersComponent{
  /**
  * some methods to configure the routes,
  */
}
```

`UsersComponent` has dynamically configured routes for users,

eg. `/alex` , `/john` etc,

since the routes are from the child component, the path looks like `example.com/users/alex`, `example.com/users/john` etc.. But I want the path to be `example.com/alex` and `example.com/john`

also I want to load the component associated with each user to the parent's `router-outlet`. In the example here, to the `router-outlet` of `App` so that I can get rid of the user list.

Thank You for any help.

Comment: Are you getting any error when following the docs? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/rCn06yZyuh7260oeguuF?p=preview) forked plunker. It works once. But If you click Users>User and then again Users it throws exception. Is it close ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take on your configuration: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k9R6ahV0cz8JJ0crrnwS?p=preview)

**1. Define your `App`'s `RouteConfig` like this**

```
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    useAsDefault: true

  },
  {
    path: '/:user',
    name: 'User',
    component: PersonComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/users',
    name: 'Users',
    component: UsersComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/contact',
    name: 'Contact',
    component: ContactComponent
  }
])
```

**2. Remove `router.config` and `<router-outlet>` from your `UsersComponent`**

Don't send the user data via `RouteData` because than you'll have to define routes for every user in advance, which is not necessary/ efficient.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template : `

    <div  *ngFor="#page of pages">
      <a [routerLink]="['User', {user: page.name}]">
        {{page.slug}}
      </a>
    </div>
  `,
  providers : [PagesService]
})
export class UsersComponent{
  pages = [];

  constructor(private pgSvc: PagesService, router: Router) {
  }
}
```

**3. Structure your service to send data for a specific user**

**4. Update your `PersonComponent` to accomodate with these changes.**

```
@Component({
  selector : 'person',
  template : `
  <div class="person-container">
    <h3>Person selected : <strong> {{data.get['user']}} </strong></h3>
  </div>
  `
})
class PersonComponent {
  constructor(public data: RouteParams) {

   // call your service here to get the user specific data by using 
    let userName = data.get('user');

   // yourService.getUserData(userName);
  }
  routerCanReuse(next, prev) {
    return false;
  }
}
```